# gdal_rasterize incorrect values scale after rasterization

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, vector

I am trying to rasterize a .shp file (in particular it is made up by several Polygon) into .tif one by using python and the gdal_rasterize command.

According to the gdal_rasterize function, I was able to set the options:

- a (the attribute that I want to be mirrored within the raster)
- tr (since I know the width and heigth pixel of each polygon)
- te (also in this case I have the     boundary of the .shp)

The conversion is correctly in terms of positions within the map. But the range of values is different w.r.t the .shp file.

The command called was:

```
 import subprocess

 def rasterize(source_shape_file, layer_name, attribute, dest_file,
               width, height, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, dest_file):

   subprocess.check_output("gdal_rasterize -a " + str(attribute) + " -l " + str(layer_name) + " -tr " 
                           + str(width) + " " +  str(height) +  "-a_nodata -1.0 -te " + str(xmin) + " 
                           " + str(ymin) + " " + str(xmax) + " " + str(ymax) + " -of GTiff " + "'" + 
                           str(source_shape_file) + "'"+ " " +str(dest_file) + "")
```

By executing this, within QGIS I was able to saw the result:

[image]

The raster value with some blue transparency completely overlap the vector layer as expected.

However the data range:

[image]

As it is possible to see, is different between the two layer.
I mean for the max and min value.

Am I doing something wrong during the execution of the command?
Or is there some option that I have ignored?

I would like to know if there is some way to obtain the same values of the vector layer inside the raster one.

Comment: One layer has distinct values in the legend, the other is using ranges. Min and max in raster are within min and max ranges of polygons. Test with legends is not a good test. Use the query tool (i) for checking the exact values of pixels and attributes.

Comment: The attribute is just one (the data one). The values are different by the way

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. If you burn the values of an attribute of the polygons into pixels, the pixel should get exactly the same value. Do you mean that you have something different? How do you know that and why did you add the image of the legend that is using data ranges (like -0.057 - -0.45) for the polygons? Minimum value of the raster is -0.0551888 and it is within the minimum category of the polygons. Classifying the polygon layer by distinct values should suit better for this kind of comparison.

Comment: Ok, within the vector layer the polygon with the highest associate value has a value of -0.015. I perfectly know the position of this polygon. Then when i rasterize this vector layer the same polygon (now is rasterized) does not have the value of -0.015, but ha the value of -0.0264643. But both of them perfectly overlap!

Comment: Interesting. Without some polygon data for testing it is hard to say anything more.